# Lisp if-statement - emacs initialization file ".emacs"

Tags: file, emacs, lisp, elisp

I modified my .emacs file to make auto-backups hidden files via the following code:

```
(defun make-backup-file-name (filename)
  (expand-file-name
   (concat "." (file-name-nondirectory filename) "~")
   (file-name-directory filename)))
```

It works great except that backups of hidden-files go from ".hidden-file.xxx" to "..no-longer-hidden-file.xxx'

I know zero Lisp, can someone give me a quick work-around like:

```
(if (filename) doesn't-start-with "."
  (concat 
  (else do-nothing))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `(equal (string-to-char filename) ?.)`. This turns the filename string into its first character and compares it to `?.`, which is the character notation for a `.`.

By the looks of it, you want to check `(file-name-nondirectory filename)` rather than just `filename`, so the whole statement would be something like:

```
(if (equal (string-to-char (file-name-nondirectory filename)) ?.)
    (concat (file-name-nondirectory filename) "~")
    (concat "." (file-name-nondirectory filename) "~"))
```

So the whole function should look something like:

```
(defun make-backup-file-name (filename)
  (expand-file-name
  (if (equal (string-to-char (file-name-nondirectory filename)) ?.)
    (concat (file-name-nondirectory filename) "~")
    (concat "." (file-name-nondirectory filename) "~"))
  (file-name-directory filename)))
```

You need to do a `concat` in both branches because you always want to append a `~`.

Comment: So the result would look like : ?
(defun make-backup-file-name (filename) \\
  (expand-file-name \\
   (if (equalp (string-to-char filename) ?.) \\
   (concat "." (file-name-nondirectory filename) "~") \\
   (file-name-directory filename))))

Comment: My whole `if` statement is meant to replace your `(concat...)` statement.

Comment: Its telling me "Symbol's function definition is void: equalp"... any ideas?

Comment: That's odd. Are you sure you spelled it correctly? Also, try using just `equal` instead.

Comment: `equalp` seems to be present in XEmacs only. I could not find any reference to it in the FSF emacs documentation.

Comment: Really? I am running GNU Emacs 23.3.1 and I have an `equalp` function.

Comment: Hm. Mine is GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (and no `equalp`). -- Not that it would matter, as `equal` works just as well here... :-)

Comment: I probably got `equalp` from some extension or other I have running--I use a ton of different modes and stuff. I think sticking to `equal` is safest in this case.

Comment: ha; now its telling me "Wrong number of arguments: equal, 1"  EDIT: just needed to change the syntax to "(equal (string-to-char (file-name-nondirectory filename)) ?.)" --- and that works!  Thanks!

Comment: I just transcribed some of the parentheses incorrectly. It should be: `(equal (string-to-char (file-name-nondirectory filename)) ?.)`. I got it correct in the top code block, but wrong in the bottom one :P

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
(if (not (string-equal (substring "abcdefg" 0 1) "."))
 (message "foo") 
 (message "bar")
)
```

Since you're in emacs, open a scratch buffer and `M-x eval-buffer` what you're doing to check that it has the right semantics. `message` is useful in debugging as it prints a string to the mini-buffer.

Answer (score 0):

you can also test (string-match "\`\." (file-name-nondirectory filename)), but to tell you the truth I wonder why you think "..foo" is considered as "not hidden": in my tests, `ls' and * both ignored my "..test.txt" file.

Comment: Yeah I realized that---Its not actually 'not hidden', just ugly and awkward